# What kind of palm tree is this?

Tags: trees, palm

[image]

As the title says.  Saw this palm tree in Florida and the wife really likes it.  Just curious what type it is.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are only about 2,000 species so we should be able to narrow this down a bit. First, the fronds (leaves) are pinnate and not palm shaped. Second  there is only one main trunk, on other species there may be multiple trunks. That should eliminate a few.

One that looks similar for example is the Canary Island Date Palm (*[Phoenix canariensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoenix_canariensis)*). The fronds are long and in its normal trimmed condition there is roughness below the canopy. Seen in Florida, Texas, California and frequently used in landscape plantings due to ease of care. The specimen in the photo is rather short for this suggestion, however; for that dbh of trunk it might be about twice the height.

Comment: That is what I thought it was after googling a bit, but I agree that it is shorter than what a canary island date palm should be.  That is why I have asked.